# SelectFeature and ModifyFeature in OpenLayers 2.13

Tags: openlayers-2

After lot of experimenting, I have to give up and ask: has anyone had success in using both SelectFeature and ModifyFeature in OL 2.13 (NB, there were changes to ModifyFeature in 2.13, compared to 2.12)?

What I want to do: ModifyFeature should work on it's regular way (user can drag points; and click on lines will bring "handles" visible). In addition, I want to catch select and hover events.

Answer (score 1):

it has been a long time since this question was asked - but: Yes I did have success in using SelectFeature and ModifyFeature. In my case the difference why the "select" Event did not throw was, that the "ModifyFeature" uses the "featuremodified" (or "beforefeaturemodified") Event and not the "featureselected" Event.

Just in case this helps somebody:

**OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature**

```
oLayers[testlayer].events.register("beforefeaturemodified", oMap, showMyInternalAttributes );
```

**OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature**

```
oLayers[testlayer].events.register("featureselected", oMap, showMyInternalAttributes );
```